# Feed-Forward ReLU Networks as a matrix multiplication

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, matrix

When reading papers, Feed-Forward NN are often formalized as follows:

$$\Phi(x) := \sigma(W_L\cdots \sigma(W_2\cdot \sigma(W_1x))\cdots) $$
i.e., the ReLU activation function $\sigma$ applied to the input $x$ transformed by layer weight matrices $W_1, \ldots, W_L$. Clearly, this formula omits the bias terms. In fact, for a single layer with weights $W$, bias $b$ and input $y$ we can write $Wy +b = [W |b] \cdot (y, 1)^T$ as a matrix-multiplication by appending a $1$ to the input.

However, how does that work for the chained application of layers as in $\Phi(x)$. For the first layer $(W_1, b_1)$ we could of course modify our data-input $x$ by appending a $1$, however the second layer $(W_2, b_2)$ will not receive an input with a trailing $1$.

What am I missing here? Can I write $\Phi$ as a matrix-multiplication and application of $\sigma$ without appending a $1$ after every layer?

Thanks!

Comment: These are series of function compositions by layer order. We could only write bias term outside of the function if activation is linear, f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b). ReLu is nonlinear.

Comment: I don't quite get your answer. Papers just use the matrix notation for the sake of simplicity and because apparently the bias term is ommitable. However, I feel like this is not possible for ReLU networks, as outlined above. Is this true?